# Interfacing Vernier equipment and microcontrollers

Tags: sensor, robotics, sound

I am the president of my high school's robotics club. We own several VeX robot kits which we have been using for a few years now.  The physics department also owns several Vernier LabPro sonic rangefinders. To save money, I want to be able to utilize the rangefinders in a navigation challenge. However, I do not know if it possible to do so mostly in software, i.e. without constructing interface boards.

The Vernier website provides that the five applicable pins are Echo, Init, AutoID, V+, and GND, in that order.  My question, for anyone who is familiar with this equipment, is: is it possible to connect to these pins through the inputs and outputs on a VeX so that the incoming data (Echo, I believe) can be used for ranging, or am I asking too much of this hardware.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give a link to exactly the Vex kit that you have? It looks like it would be possible, but it depends on the details.

Comment: Certainly: http://www.vexrobotics.com/catalog/product/view/id/12217/s/dual-control-starter-bundle/category/1579/

Comment: Please link the datasheet of the rangefinder

Answer (score 1):

Try this link
http://www.nerdkits.com/videos/digital_calipers_dro/

(Step-by-step description of adding a USB interface and pair of digital calipers to a milling machine for digital readout).

Comment: @joe, The community often takes simple redirect to a companies site poorly, I am really happy you have taken the time to join our little community, but why not expand here on what the product is and its value, then give us a link if we want to learn "more."